# Qt5 on iMX6: how to make sure the hardware acceleration is in use?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, imx6

I have a `Qt5` application using `Qwt` Library for plotting a few traces, with graphic zoom, and some other simple Qt widgets, like `QLabel`, `QPushButton`, `QScrollBar`, `QFrame` and the like.

The application is running on Linux.

Linux kernel is 3.10.17.

Distribution is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty).

Qt version is 5.2.1.

My question is:
What should I do to make sure the iMX6 built-in GPU hardware acceleration is in use?
Do I need to specify:

```
QT += opengl
```

in `Qt` .pro project file?

Regarding `Qwt`, is it enough to use `QwtPlotGLCanvas`?

Are those the best that I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various `QWidget` classes you mentioned (`QLabel`, `QPushButton`, etc.) will not be drawn taking advantage of hardware acceleration. They will use Qt's standard raster paint engine (`QPainter`).

Only classes that render using OpenGL will take advantage of the 3D graphics hardware in your i.MX6 (`QGLWidget`, Qt Quick, etc.). I have never used `QwtPlotGLCanvas`, but since its name includes GL, it most likely is drawing to a GL surface and should be taking advantage of the OpenGL acceleration your platform provides.